# Renaming multiple files at once with Python

Tags: python

I am new to programming. I usually learn for a while , then take a long break and forget most of what I learned. Nevermind that back info.

I tried to create a function which would help me rename files inside a folder and then add an increment at the end of the new name (e.g. blueberry1, blueberry 2,...)

```
import os
def rename_files(loc,new_name):
    file_list= os.listdir(loc)
    for file_name in file_list:
        count=1
        if count <= len(file_list):
            composite_name = new_name+str(count)
            os.rename(file_name, composite_name)
            count+= 1
```

Well apparently this code doesn't work. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: post the error report.

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Have you tried adding debug statements to show what is happening

Comment: I ran this code and i can see it renaming what ever it comes across.A quick question, do you want to rename folders that reside the "loc" or not ?

Comment: just an idea: `file_name` and `composite_name` are only the Names of the Files, without the Path. Dont know if this is enough for `os.rename()`.

Comment: @cafebabe1991 : I wanted to rename all image files(jpg and png) inside the folder for documentation purposes.

Comment: @GarethOakeley : The specific error was : WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the file to the path:

```
 os.rename(os.path.join(loc, file_name), composite_name)
```

You can also use enumerate for the count:

```
import os
def rename_files(loc,new_name):
    file_list= os.listdir(loc)
    for ind, file_name in enumerate(file_list,1):
            composite_name = new_name+str(ind)
            os.rename(os.path.join(loc, file_name), os.path.join(loc, composite_name)
```

`listdir` just  returns the file names, not the path so python would have no way of knowing where the original file actually came from unless your cwd was the same directory.

Comment: Well, I ran your suggested code and the same error pops up.                 File , line 3, in rename_files
 file_list= os.listdir(loc)
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified

Comment: How did you pass the path? Did you use raw string or escape the backslashes?

Comment: I entered the path as raw string.

Comment: rename_files(r"A:/Poze/2015.07.13_Slovenia_and_Croatia", "Slovenia_Croatia")

Comment: You realise this will rename all files in the directory? Also you can cd to `A:/Poze/2015.07.13_Slovenia_and_Croatia`?

Comment: As I said before I am pretty much a newbie. I haven't ever tried to cd via Python. I am only familiar with it via Windows prompt commands. So how should I do that?

Comment: I just meant that from a cmd prompt if you can change to that directory, if that path is correct the code should work fine

Comment: Yes, I can change to that directory via CD.

Comment: from a python shell what does `os.listdir(r"A:/Poze/2015.07.13_Slovenia_and_Croatia")` output?

Comment: It prints out the list with the contents of the folder.

Comment: can you add the full traceback either to your question or a pastebin link

Comment: It works now for some reason. I don't know what the issue was, but it works now with the code you suggested. Thanks a million.